# Salesforce Shield Encryption - official video showing invalid information

Tags: data, encryption, shield-encryption, salesforce-data-mask

I was looking into Salesforce Shield Encryption.

Apparently Salesforce Shield Encryption does not mask any data, but encrypts the data at rest, which means only at the database level. Anyone who has authenticated access to the data can see the encrypted data.

[The official video shows record information becoming masked in the UI.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dCt2Tzsum2Y#t=00m52s) This is truly confusing, since the user is authenticated on the video and should not see the record values masked.

- It seems there is invalid information about Salesforce Shield
  Encryption shown in the video. Am I right or wrong?
- Also one more additional question: Does Salesforce by the existence
  of Shield Encryption admit the possibility of the data being hacked,
  and therefore admits that the system might not be 100% safe?

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I am a Salesforce employee; this is not an official statement on behalf of Salesforce*.

I strongly recommend that you reference the [official documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_pe_overview.htm) rather than six-year-old YouTube videos. The platform has changed extensively since that video was created.

Note that there are a few [circumstances](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_pe_masking.htm) when you'll see Platform Encrypted data masked, but this is not a primary objective or capability of Shield Platform Encryption:

> With Shield Platform Encryption, if a user is authorized to see a given set of data, that user sees that data whether it’s encrypted or not.

---

> Does Salesforce by the existence of Shield Encryption admit the possibility of the data being hacked, and therefore admits that the system might not be 100% safe?

Only you in consultation with your compliance personnel can determine whether Shield Platform Encryption will meet your specific data protection needs, and you should carefully review the capabilities and terms for Shield Platform Encryption with your counsel.

There is no such thing as a 100% safe system, anywhere. The Shield Platform Encryption feature does not imply by its existence any weakness in the Salesforce security posture without that feature. Salesforce publishes [extensive material](https://security.salesforce.com/) on the security of the platform.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The video might be six years old, but it's an official Salesforce video nonetheless. I would have given you the exact place where I found it (I think it was on [ShieldLearningMap](https://shieldlearningmap.com/), but it seems it's offline now (says "Application error"). I don't blame you for the contradicting information in the official video and in the documentation. Have a nice day.